# FirebaseUI only allowing users to create an account but not sign-in to exsiting account

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have setup FirebaseUI in my React app so that users can create an account and sign in to said account to access my application. Whenever a user creates an account it appears to be properly saved in firebase, however, when that user tries to sign in to their account they are asked to create an account again rather then being asked for their password so they can sign in to their existing account. If the user tries to create another account useing the same email they get an error message --> This email already exists without any means of sign-in. Please reset the password to recover. <--

This is the code for the fire base implemtation as i said almost everthing seems to working as intended except for the fact that I am always directed to create a new account even when the email I entered is already associated with an account saved in firebase. I followed a tutorial video to get this to work and I have throughly check, my code is identical to the guys code from the video yet his implementation allows him to sign in properly after having created an account whereas mine only lets me create an account but not sign in to said account.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui';
import "firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css";
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";

const AuthGoogle = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const ui =
            firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance() ||
            new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(props.auth);
        ui.start(".firebase-auth-container", {
            signInOptions: [
                {
                   provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
                }
            ],
            signInSuccessUrl: '/app'
        });
    }, [props.auth]);
    return (
        <>
            <div className="firebase-auth-container"></div>
        </>
    );
};

export default AuthGoogle;
Updated version of the code based on answer suggestions, had to alter the suggestion slightly to resolve errors but even after fixing the errors the sign-in issue persists users are always prompted to create an account rather than being able to sign in to there existing account.   

import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "firebase/auth";
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui';
import "firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css";
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";

const AuthGoogle = (props) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        const uiConfig = {
            signInFlow: 'popup',
            signInOptions: [
                {
                 provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                 requireDisplayName: false
                }
            ],
            callbacks: {
                signInSuccessWithAuthResult: () => {
                    navigate('/app');
                    return false;
                },
            },
        };

        let ui = firebaseui.auth.AuthUI.getInstance() || new 
        firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(props.auth);


        ui.start('.firebase-auth-container', uiConfig);

    }, [props.auth, navigate]);

    return (
        <div className="firebase-auth-container"></div>
    );
};

export default AuthGoogle;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the newly introduced [email enumeration protection](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection#disable), which breaks email auth for firebaseui. It can be disabled like this:

```bash
PROJECT_ID="TODO:set this to project id"
ACCESS_TOKEN="$(gcloud auth print-access-token --project="$PROJECT_ID")"
# Disable email enumeration protection
curl -X PATCH -d "{'email_privacy_config':{'enable_improved_email_privacy':"false"}}" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "X-Goog-User-Project: $PROJECT_ID" \
    "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/admin/v2/projects/$PROJECT_ID/config?updateMask=email_privacy_config"
```

Comment: Confirming that this fixed it for me too.  Crazy that you have to use curl to set this...

Comment: I ended up handling it from the Firebase console as suggested [here](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/email-enumeration-protection#disable).  I hope they fix this

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of Peter Neumark's answer - thank you so much - which worked for me from Windows cmd line

```
    curl -X PATCH -d "{'email_privacy_config':{'enable_improved_email_privacy':"false"}}" -H "Authorization: Bearer %ACCESS_TOKEN%" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Goog-User-Project: %PROJECT_ID%" "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/admin/v2/projects/%PROJECT_ID%/config?updateMask=email_privacy_config"
```

There were missing inverted commas on one argument and the reference to the variable needed to change for windows.

I lost 3 days trying to figure this out - with no meaningful error messaging from the firebase UI.